# Error updating Thingsboard from 3.5.1PE to 3.6.0PE System is down :C

Tags: java, postgresql, server, cassandra, thingsboard

Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Anyone that had this problem before? Our installation in via Docker.